# Where is Info.plst in App Playground Project?

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground, realitykit

I created an App Playground with the code below:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ARContainer()
    }
}

struct ARContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.cameraMode = .ar                  // IMPORTANT
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

When it's runned to the target device, the error showed

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
> data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
> an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
> user how the app uses this data.

How to config an NSCameraUsageDescription in Info.plst?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Playgrounds**

The Swift Playgrounds equivalent of Info.plist is the App Settings item.

On the left side of the window below the search bar is an App Settings item. Click that item to open a sheet.

Below a list of possible app icons is a Capabilities item. Click the item. Click the Add button at the top of the sheet to add a capability, Camera in your case.

**Xcode**

If you created a Swift Playgrounds App project in Xcode, select the name of the project from the left side of the project window to open the project editor. Click the Signing and Capabilities button at the top of the project editor. Click the Add Capability button at the top of the project editor to add a capability, such as the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Some Info.plist keys are configured via the capabilities you add to the Playground app in the UI of either Swift Playgrounds or Xcode. But if those don't cover you, read [this blog post](https://www.rambo.codes/posts/2021-12-28-a-document-based-app-in-swift-playgrounds-for-ipad) for information on how to add an additional Info.plist file that will be merged into the app bundle on build.